# Why doesn't setter change the value in C++?

Tags: c++

The following code prints:

```
2
1
```

instead of

```
2
2
```

Why is my setter not adjusting the value?

### Main

```
Vector location = camera.get_location();
camera.get_location().set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
std::cout << location.get_y() + 1 << std::endl;
std::cout << camera.get_location().get_y() << std::endl;
```

### camera.h

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include "vector.h"

class Camera {
 private:
  Vector location;
 public:
  Vector get_location();
  void set_location(Vector);
};

#endif
```

### camera.cpp

```
#include "camera.h"

Vector Camera::get_location() { return location; }
void Camera::set_location(Vector l) { location = l; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
camera.get_location().set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
```

`get_location` returns a *copy* of the original object. So `set_y` does modify `y` **but** it is  modiying the *copy* of the original location. If you want the above to work as you expect, then return *reference*:

```
Vector & get_location();
```

The function-body will be same as before:

```
Vector& Camera::get_location() { return location; }
```

Now it will work the way you expected.

You could write the code as:

```
Vector  & location = camera.get_location(); //save the reference
location.set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
```

It modifies the `camera`'s location object.

Compare the above code with this:

```
Vector location = camera.get_location(); //save the copy!
location.set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
```

It does NOT modify `camera`'s location object! It modifies the copy, not the original.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ha! Thanks! I'm still getting used to these things.

Answer (score 1):

```
camera.get_location().set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
```

Is setting the `y` of a temporary vector instead of modifying `camera`'s vector.

You would have to do it like this:

```
Vector new_vector = camera.get_location;
new_vector.set_y(location.get_y() + 1);
camera.set_location(new_vector)
```

A better idea is just avoid using getters and setters.

Comment: I have some arguments against making the variables public/protected and I can't use functions like camera.moveLeft() or camera.moveWest() since those imply a direction or a bearing which isn't necessarily there.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter `Camera::get_location()` returns a `Vector` object. This ends up being a copy of its member variable. Thus any changes to this do not modify the `Vector` contained within the `Camera`.

If you want this to be modifiable you should change it to return a `Vector&` reference.